# What are the sample spaces and event in the following question?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

There is a group of 10 people. 5 of them have gone through Covid-19 testing. Out of these 5, 3 were found +ve and 2 were found -ve. Rest 5 people have not gone through any testing.

Now, I want to find what is the probability of a random person choose to be +ve.

I need to find, what are the sample spaces in this problem, and in how many ways chose people can be found +ve?

Actually, I'm confused, how to approach this problem?

And how do I get convince that, my approach is correct?

My approach is
$\frac{1\cdot 3 + 0.5\cdot 5}{3 + 2 + 5 } = 0.55$.

I'm not convinced with my approach.

Thank you.

Comment: Why did you do $0.5\times 5$?  Where did you hear anything about the people who haven't gone through any testing?

Comment: @JMoravitz basically, for the rest 5 people, it's unknown, whether they are Covid-19 +ve or -ve..

Comment: If you are assuming that the not tested people are positive or negative with 1/2 probability, then your approach is correct

Answer (score 1):

In your event space, you should account for every possible condition (+ve or -ve) of the non-tested people, and every choice of the random person. As a consequence, you have
 $$
\Omega = (+,+,+,-,-) \times \{+,-\}^5 \times \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}
$$
As an example, an event is $(+,+,+,-,-,-,-,+,-,+,6)$. A single event is associated with the probability $(\frac 12)^5\frac 1{10}$, since you have $2^5$ ways to choose the condition of the 5 nontested people, and $10$ ways of selecting a random person.

The random variable $X$ you want to consider tells whether the chosen person in +ve or -ve. In particular, you can assign $1$ to positive and $0$ to negative. For example $X(+,+,+,-,-,-,-,+,-,+,6) = 0$ because the sixth person is negative.

If you want to compute the probability the selected person is positive, it is just $\mathbb P(X^{-1}(1))$, also said $\mathbb P(X=1)$. Since all the events are equiprobable, you just have to count how many events there are in $X^{-1}(1)$ and divide the number by $2^5*10 =320$. You can verify with your argument that such number is $3*2^5 + 5*2^4 = 96 + 80 = 176$ and $176/320 = 0.55$